# insert query not working more than 20 times

Tags: php, html, mysql

i am using HTML And PHP to save some data in Database but unfortunately the insert query is not executed not more than 20 times. Actually in my web interface i have created a row of some input fields like name, father name and one pdf file for uploading. There are two buttons at the bottom, one button is used for adding one more row of fields and the other for saving. The code is working 100% fine when user enters not more than 20 records when user enters more than 20 records than insert query is executed only 20 times, and rest of the records are ignored. here is my sample code

HTML Code

```
<td height="30"><input type="text" name="a[]" size="5" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="b[]" size="10" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="c[]" size="40" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="d[]" size="10" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="e[]" size="10" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="f[]" size="10" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="g[]" class="datepick" 
    id="exdate" size="15" onclick="function()"/></td>
<td><input type="file" name="h[]" size="15"  id="file" 
    accept="application/msexcel, application/msword, application/pdf, 
    image/gif, image/png, image/jpg, image/jpeg" />
```

PHP Code

```
        $recs = count($_POST["a"]);
        for($i = 0; $i <= $recs - 1; $i++) {
            $a = $i + 1;
            $file_name = $_FILES["file"]["name"][$i];
            $ext = strrchr($file_name, ".");
            $path = "bb/".$newname."-".$a.$ext;
            $status = 1;
            $date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST["ex"][$i]));
            $query = "INSERT INTO abc (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,g,i,j,k) 
                VALUES (
                    '".$_POST["a"][$i]."', 
                    '".$_POST["b"][$i]."',
                    '".$_POST["c"][$i]."',
                    '".$_POST["d"][$i]."',
                    '".$newname."',
                    '".$_POST["e"][$i]."', 
                    '".$path."',
                    '".$f."',
                    '".$_POST["g"][$i]."',
                    '".$date."',
                    '".$h."'
                );";
            mysql_query($query) or die("Mistake in query");
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$i], $path);
        }
    }
    header("Location: save.php?saved=true");
}
```

I am unable to understand whether there is any default size of input box which restricting it or there is any mistake in php code

Comment: 1. Stop using the `mysql_` functions - they've been deprecated for years. Use MySQLi or PDO instead with prepared statements. 2. Your code is very vunerable towards SQL injection - it wouldn't be if you used prepared statements and bound variables. 3. Always `exit` or `die` after setting a location header or the script will continue on. 4. Don't or `or die()` - use regular error handling instead.

Comment: u need to check max_file_upload limit. Looks like u are uploading file in each loop and when the limit breaks the code also breaks.

Comment: @h2ooooooo not sure code gets interpreted after a `header()` relocation (I actually think it isn't).

Comment: I can't see an error with the fragment of code you have given. If you try a `print_r($_POST);` do you get the full number of input elements or just the first 20?

Comment: @Loïc Feel free to test it `<?php header('Location: http://www.google.com'); file_put_contents('this_exists.txt', 'foo'); ?>`

Comment: let me check with print_r..

Answer (score 0):

Your code has multiple flaws:

- `$f` and `$h` are not being set
- you are inserting into `(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,g,i,j,k)`. Notice `g` there twice.
- You don't escape your input, making an apostrophe `'` in any of the fields break your code. Use `mysql_real_escape_string()` ... or better yet, don't use `mysql_` functions at all, but rather use `mysqli_` functions or `PDO` functions.
- Uploading too many files will hit the max post value set for php and/or webserver. (check the values in php.ini and httpd.conf if you are using apache.)

Comment: May be there will be mistakes, But as i mentioned, Its just a sample code

Answer (score -1):

try this: remove the `;` in your insert query

your code:

```
 '".$f."',
    '".$_POST["g"][$i]."',
    '".$date."',
    '".$h."'
    );";       ----> remove the ;
```

correct code:

```
   '".$f."',
    '".$_POST["g"][$i]."',
    '".$date."',
    '".$h."'
    )";
```